# Kibana - Update field value from discover view

Tags: kibana, opensearch

I want to know if following flow is possible.
Discover the Index data, selecting the field that I want to update, pop up windows revield, I am entering the new value and saving it. Updated value shown.

I thought using calculated field for this popuuse but got lost trying to implement the flow.